# check if series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+{(-1)^n}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There's the series:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}{+(-1)^n}}$$

I have no clue which test should I use to check it properly

Root test gives nothing right as well as Ratio test. I suspect there's a trap

Comment: First cancel the $(-1)^n$s. Then there's just $\sum n^{-1/2}$ left. But that has the harmonic series (well known to diverge) as a subsequence!

Comment: The series you are asked about might be $$\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$$ Note that this means *two* modifications. // Now to your personal input...

Comment: We recommend avoiding division by zero by the way.

Comment: Are you sure that the bounds are from $n=1$ to $\infty$? Try plugging in $n=1$.

Comment: thats why I am in doubts. maybe there's a typo in the task....

Comment: @projectilemotion. May be, this is **the** trap !

Comment: Oddly, only one modification suggested in my previous comment was adopted by the OP, leading to comments about dividing by zero, that the question still neglects. Reading said comment carefully was something impossible, it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$ diverges.

To show this we write the partial sums of the series as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}&=\color{blue}{\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}_{\text{Converges as}\,\,N\to \infty}}-\color{red}{\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n)}\right)}_{\text{Diverges as}\,\,N\to \infty}}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Leibniz's test guarantees that the limit first term converges as $N\to \infty$.

However, for the second term on the right, we have

$$\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n)}\ge \frac12 \sum_{n=2}^N\frac1{n}$$

which shows that the second term diverges by comparison to the harmonic series.

> Inasmuch as the partial sums of the series of interest are comprised of the partial sums of a convergent series and the partial sums of a divergent series, the series of interest diverges.

Answer (score 3):

For the *new* version
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}
$$
The alternating series does not apply since the terms do not decrease in absolute value.  However, group the terms in twos
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{2k-1}}{\sqrt{2k-1}+(-1)^{2k-1}} +
\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{\sqrt{2k}+(-1)^{2k}}\right)
$$

but this term is
$$
\left(\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{2k-1}+(-1)} +
\frac{(+1)}{\sqrt{2k}+(+1)}\right)
=\frac{\sqrt{2k-1}-1-\sqrt{2k}-1}{\big(\sqrt{2k-1}-1\big)\big(\sqrt{2k}+1\big)} \\ <
\frac{-1}{\big(\sqrt{2k-1}-1\big)\big(\sqrt{2k}+1\big)} < 0
$$
These terms are all negative, so you can show divergence
by comparison to $\sum (-1/k)$.